# Unable to connect to aersopike db via python - failed to connect to the cluster with [('127.0.0.1', 3000)]

Tags: java, python, vagrant, aerospike

I have Aerospike running via Vagrant on a virtual box which is running on a windows system.

I have a Java Spring Boot application running on windows which is able to talk to the aerospike db on host 127.0.0.1 and port 3000.

Here is my properties file -

```
prepaid.aerospike.namespace=hello
prepaid.aerospike.hosts.count=1

prepaid.aerospike.hostname1=127.0.0.1
prepaid.aerospike.port1=3000

prepaid.aerospike.sequence.namespace=hello1
```

And here is the AerospikeConfiguration file -

```
package com.citruspay.common.prepaid.aerospike;

import java.util.Properties;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import com.aerospike.client.AerospikeException;
import com.aerospike.client.Host;
import com.spikeify.Spikeify;

@Configuration
public class AerospikeConfiguration {

    @Value("${prepaid.aerospike.namespace}")
    private String namespace;

    @Value("${prepaid.aerospike.hosts.count}")
    private String aerospikeHostCount;

    @Value("${prepaid.um.aerospike.cache.namespace}")
    private String aerospikeUMCacheNamespace;

    @Value("${prepaid.aerospike.history.namespace}")
    private String aerospikeHistoryNamespace;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("configProperties")
    Properties config;

    public Host[] aerospikeHosts() {
        Integer hostsCount = Integer.parseInt(aerospikeHostCount);
        Host[] hosts = new Host[hostsCount];
        for (int i = 1; i <= hostsCount; i++) {
            hosts[i - 1] = new Host(
                    config.getProperty("prepaid.aerospike.hostname" + i),
                    Integer.parseInt(
                            config.getProperty("prepaid.aerospike.port" + i)));
        }
        return hosts;
    }

    @Bean
    public Spikeify spikeify() throws AerospikeException {
        SpikeifyService.globalConfig(namespace, aerospikeHosts());
        return SpikeifyService.sfy();
    }

    public String getNamespace() {
        return namespace;
    }

}
```

**Problem**

I have python for windows running on my system.

I tried running exactly the same example given in https://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/python

On running the python file via python aerospike.py, I get -

```
failed to connect to the cluster with [('127.0.0.1', 3000)]
```

**Update**

Network section from aerospike.conf-

```
network {
        service {
                address any
                port 3000
        }

        heartbeat {
                mode mesh
                port 3002 # Heartbeat port for this node.
#               address 127.0.0.1
                # List one or more other nodes, one ip-address & port per line:
                #                 #               mesh-seed-address-port 10.10.10.11 3002
                #                 #               mesh-seed-address-port 10.10.10.12 3002
                #                 #               mesh-seed-address-port 10.10.10.13 3002
                #                 #               mesh-seed-address-port 10.10.10.14 3002
                #
                #                                 interval 250
                #                                                 timeout 10
                #
        }

        fabric {
                port 3001
        }

        info {
                port 3003
        }
}
```

Comment: What IP address/port is Aerospike bound to?  Are you running any firewall?

Comment: How do I check that? `tasklist` command is showing vagrant - `Image Name                     PID Session Name        Session#    Mem Usage` -> `vagrant.exe                  12912 Console                    1      2,552 K`

Comment: Do you have access-address configured in your aerospike.conf? can you run asinfo -v service within your vagrant box and see which IP are advertised to clients.

Comment: @lvolmar No, I do not have access-address configured in aerospike.conf. The output of `asinfo -v service` shows two IP-port combinations. These are not my localhost IP. I am not sure where are they configured.

Comment: You need to find your aerospike.conf file and show it here. It'll be in your vagrant instance, typically at `/etc/aerospike/aerospike.conf`. Something in your configuration is limiting access from the client. See: https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/network/general/index.html

Comment: @RonenBotzer added aerospike.conf content. Please see question update.

Comment: Is that truncated? It's missing the `network` section. For reference see https://www.aerospike.com/docs/operations/configure/index.html

Comment: @RonenBotzer, sorry. Added the network section now.

Comment: That looks normal. Can you show a snippet of Python that isn’t connecting? I assume both the Java app and Python script are running on that machine, rather than connecting from somewhere else, where you’d need to provide that VM’s eth0 or eth1 IP address

Comment: Now I am getting a different error when I tried running a new python script -     `import aerospike
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aerospike'`. Trying to install aerospike for python does not work. Looks like it is not supported - https://discuss.aerospike.com/t/client-library-for-python-cant-be-installed-on-windows/1065.

Comment: Okay, next time mention what the client OS is (Windows) and we can skip the comment chain.

Answer (score 2):

The Python client is not currently supported on Windows. You can try to get it to build using the [C client](https://www.aerospike.com/download/client/c/latest/) for Windows. Please fork the [aerospike/aerospike-client-python](https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-client-python/) and contribute back the changes, if you get it to work.